# Call to a member function encode() on string

Tags: authentication, laravel-10, tymon-jwt

I'm trying to create an authentication system with laravel 10. My research led me to Tymon. But when I try to use `Auth::attempt($credentials)` for login, I get the error: `Call to a member function encode() on string`

Here is my login function... I precise that I want to log users with phone number instead of email.

```
    {
        $request->validate([
            'phone' => 'required | string',
            'password' => 'required | string'
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('phone', 'password');
        $token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials);

        if (!$token) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        $user = Auth::user();
        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user, 'authorization' => [
                'token' => $token,
                'type' => 'bearer'
            ]
        ], 200);
    }



And the error is : 
Error: Call to a member function encode() on string in file /Users/path-to-my-project/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Manager.php on line 82
```